# Highlight open apps on dash in Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: gnome, launcher, dock

This is a very pedantic question. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my desktop and recently switched from Unity to Ubuntu Gnome (3.18.5). I'm using the excellent [Dash to Dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/) extension.

My pet peeve is that when I open an app that I installed, it is not highlighted with a blue line in the dock, unlike system apps like Terminal. For example, the Brave browser that is open here -

[image: Brave no highlighted]

Moreover, if I click on the icon for Brave again, it closes the running instance and starts a new one. If I enable "Show Running Applications" from the extension settings...

[image]

... the running application is shown as a new instance in the dock, unnecessarily extending it.

[image]

How can I get my system to highlight the running app at its place in the dock itself?

EDIT : This lack of highlight only happens for apps that I've installed later - using snaps or PPAs.

Comment: Does this happen with Brave only? What about Firefox? What about another app you installed?

Comment: It happens with any other app I installed. For e.g. Keepass (icon next to Brave).

Comment: Strange! Do you have **Launch new instance** (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/600/launch-new-instance/) or something similar activated?

Comment: Nope. Checked that already.

Comment: What happens when you're in the 2-icons-situation as in the 3rd screenshot, if you right-click and **Remove from Favourites** the icon without the running indicator and **Add to Favourites** the one with indicator?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes.

Comment: Perhaps,  the pre-installed apps on the dash have a description in some specific location. And I need to add similar descriptions for the apps I've installed. If it helps, most of these apps have been installed as snaps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63314/discussion-between-pomsky-and-user1649740).

Answer (score 0):

In the `Dash to Dock` settings, try these settings...

[image]

[image]

**Update #1:**

The user's problem only occurs with snap applications. Suggested to contact the author of `Dash to Dock` and report a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this does not work. It only replaces the blue highlights with dots. And that too, only for the pre-installed apps.

Comment: @user1649740  I just checked mine, and it properly shows the white dot for running apps that weren't installed as favorites. You might write the author of DtD and see if they can help.

Comment: ps: I wonder if it's a bug... move the dock back to the left side and see if the white dots show up.

Comment: @user1649740 Are the only icon/highlight problems that you're having are with snap applications? If so, I'd report that to the DtD author.

Comment: 1. Moving the dock to the left did not affect any change.
2. Yes, currently, the problem is only with applications installed as snaps. Moreover, every time I click on the new icons, a new instance of the app is generated rather than pulling up an existing one that is already running.